# How to evaluate $\int_{0} ^{2}\frac{(x-⌊x⌋)dx}{2x+1-⌊x⌋}$

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to evaluate $\int_{0} ^{2}\frac{(x-⌊x⌋)dx}{2x+1-⌊x⌋}$. How can I do this? Can it be done just with the graph of the function? We have $[x] =x-\{x\}$ and after this the graph would follow. But without that, how can it be solved?

Is there  a **general** way to approach such functions?

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor $ behaves nicely between $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$; split the integral up accordingly

Comment: How do i know to split it at 1? Because the floor function 's discontinuities are integers only?

Comment: Yes, you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: [x] =0 for x in [0,1)and 1 for x in [1, 2)

Comment: Mathematica answers $\frac{1}{4} (4-2 \log (2)-\log (3))$.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to do this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x-\lfloor x\rfloor=n+\{x\}$ where $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$

$2x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor=2n+\{x\}+1$

so we can split up your integral into two parts:
$$f(x)=\frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{2x+1-\lfloor x\rfloor}=\begin{cases}\frac{y}{y+1} & 0\le x<1\\\frac{1+y}{3+y}&1\le x<2\end{cases}$$
where $y\in[0,1)$